# How to get Socket to send to the requesting client only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am having an issue practicing with socket.io. I have a function set up, where on connection, the users data is refreshed, only it seems to only be happening AFTER the initial connection.

When one user connects, nothing on new user refreshes. Aditional new user connects, Old connection refreshes, but new connection remains untouched.

Am I not able to send data during connection?

This is just some simple practice for me, trying to get better with websockets, and can't seem to get past the general broadcast.emit.

I have tried socket.to(socket.id).broadcast.emit, of course, however no luck there either. You will see in my code.

```
// Setup socket.io
socketIo.on('connection', socket => {


        getDataByUser(user, socket)



    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      delete CLIENTS[socket.id];
      console.log(`${username} disconnected`)
    });




function getDataByUser(user, socket) {



    var items = [1,2,3];
    items.forEach(element => {      
    socket.broadcast.emit('server:data', element)
      socket.broadcast.to(socket.id).emit('data', 'for your eyes only');
    });
}
```

As you can see in the getData function, I use both a general emit, and an emit to, in order to test it. I have proper listeners set up, however the socket itself is only refreshed apon a new connection.  Perhaps this is only called when socket a makes a new connection?

I would like to have this function called imediately apon socket connection. for only the user who has connected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you can deal with this is to not broadcast it.
Try to emit only to the socket who got connected at that time.
I did not get what you are trying to achieve so if the code below does not resolve you problem please say what output do you expect.

```
socketIo.on('connection', socket => {


     var items = [1,2,3];
    items.forEach(element => {      
    socket.emit('server:data', element)
    socket.emit('data', 'for your eyes only');
    });



socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  socket.disconnect();
  console.log(`${username} disconnected`)
});
```

when you use the socket object you adress to that client only...the one who establised the connection.